# Can't run any Virtualization processes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to run a vm in virtualbox and I need AMD-V access but I always get the error that the AMD-V is not available. I have looked up my processers model and it does support amd-v and I have checked that virtualization is enabled in the bios. When I go into task manager it says virtualization is enabled. When I try to install the haxm for android studio it says the same thing. I have tried installing bluestacks to check also and I got the same error that virtualization is being used. Bluestacks used to work (years ago) so I know my computer can do virtualization. I have checked in windows defender and the virtualization based protecter is turned off. I only have windows 10 home so I dont have Hyper-V. Are there any more processes that might be using virtualization. Would turning Virtualization off in the bios, keeping it off for a few days, and then turning it back on kill whatever is using it? If I turned off virtualization would there be a log in the system event log of the application that couldnt start because it needs virtualization? Any ideas?

Comment: So you are sure you have Virtualization switched on in the UEFI Bios. Then if you go to "Settings -- Apps -- Programs and Features -- Activate or deactivate Windows features": Is "Windows Hypervisor platform" (almost at the bottom) switched on? And in the middle: "Platform for virtual computers" as well? (not sure about the exact names, I have to translate them)

Comment: I see you cannot comment under 50 points :(.

Comment: A question author can always submit a comment to their own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned Windows Hypervisor platform off and then back on and it started working.

Comment: This is the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 10 Home does not have Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v), but you can go to

"Settings -- Apps -- Programs and Features -- Activate or deactivate Windows features"

and check whether "Windows Hypervisor platform" (almost at the bottom) is switched on,  and in the middle: "Platform for virtual computers" as well (not sure about the exact names, I have to translate them).

I have recently installed WSL2 on my Windows 10 Home, and I had the same question. Quote from the Microsoft forum [How can WSL 2 powered by Hyper-V be on Windows 10 HomeV?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_tools/how-can-wsl-2-powered-by-hyper-v-be-on-windows-10/b03c0096-02d9-44e7-b832-2c6ee2f5a064):

> WSL 2 is available on all SKUs where WSL is currently available,
> including Windows 10 Home.
>
> The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its
> virtualization. This architecture will be available in the 'Virtual
> Machine Platform' optional component. This optional component will be
> available on all SKUs. You can expect to see more details about this
> experience soon as we get closer to the WSL 2 release.
>
> You would see Virtual Machine platform component in Windows 10 Home as
> well(turn windows features on/off).

Double check whether Virtual Machine is enabled. From https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-wsl2-windows-10, again, for WSL2, but should help you as well:

> Enabling Virtual Machine
>
> If you don't already have this enabled, you'll need to turn it on
> before installing WSL2. As already stated, WSL2 is a tiny virtual
> machine, so Windows 10 needs to be prepared for that. If you have this
> enabled already, skip and go straight to rebooting your PC to make
> sure you're ready to install.
>
> The quickest way to do it is in PowerShell. Open PowerShell as
> administrator and enter this command:
>
> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform
> /all /norestart
>
> Now reboot your PC and move to the next section.

Comment: I turned `Windows Hypervisor platform` off and then back on and it worked.

Comment: @EthanO'Brien That is a new answer, please add and accept it, since I did not know that trick. Good idea.